# Schedule Something On a Click of the Calendar Control

Tags: c#

I am designing a GUI with the Form Designer and I need to schedule something. I have the the calendar on the form. I was wondering if their was a way to take the click on a certain date and make that set a variable that would make it so a certain function would take place on that date.

**EDIT**
Actually, I might want to do a day of the week and time instead.  Would this work the same way?

Answer (score 1):

There is an event when a date is selected. You can use that event to schedule something.

This assumes you know how to use events, and that you know how to schedule something. If you don't, then you should ask separate questions, though you should probably search the site to see if the question has already been asked and answered.